# Как переадресовать пользователя на локализованную страницу wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, локализация

Есть сайт на `wordpress` с мультиязычностью, которая реализована с помощью [плагина wpml](https://wpml.org/).
Мне нужно настроить переадресацию со станицы обработки `php` на главную локализованную страницу, к примеру http://example.com/ http://example.com/ua http://example.com/de и т.п.
Проблема в том, что инструкции

`wp_redirect( home_url(), 301 );`

и

`wp_redirect( apply_filters( 'wpml_home_url', get_option( 'home' )), 301 );`

адресуют каждый раз на главную http://example.com/ не учитывая локализации сайта на котором был пользователь. Как поправить,

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй [wpml_home_url](https://wpml.org/wpml-hook/wpml_home_url/) вместо `home_url`

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/502591)

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica это не замечание или уточнение, а именно ответ

Comment: @Az Rieil а в чем отличие моего и вашего варианта `wp_redirect( apply_filters( 'wpml_home_url', get_option( 'home' )), 301 );` ?

Comment: хм. не увидел
1. в General settings -> Site address прописан путь?
2. в WPML -> settings -> "Language URL format" выбрано Different languages in directories ?" 
3.